# In EE 2.9.1 is there a way to removed default fields from the registration page?

Tags: ee2, fields, registration

In EE 2.9.1 is there a way to removed default fields from the registration page?  I see that I can create fields that add to the registration page, but I don't see a way to remove default fields.  Surely someone other myself has had this thought before.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are are a number of options open to you:

1. Edit the default member registration template in Design->Templates->Themes->Member Profile Templates
2. Use an add-on like [Freemember](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freemember)
3. Create your own custom registration form